# return object in node js after forEach finishes

Tags: node.js

I know node.js is asynchronous but I couldn't find any library or workaround to make this work. I have a `couchbase` database behind and I want to retrieve some values from multiple documents.

Below it's my sample code:

```
devices.forEach(function(type) {
  bucket.get("typeids", function(error, id) {
    id.value.forEach(function(id) {
      bucket.get(type+"+"+id, function(error, device) {
        bucket.get(type+"+"+id+"+l", function(error, location) {
          device.value["location"] = location.value.room;
          result.push(device.value);
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

How can I return the `result` array with the objects inside after everything is executed?

Comment: Are you using Node 7+? If you are, I highly advise async/await.

Comment: I am using version 7.0.0 :)

Comment: Lookup closures and running async operations in for loops in nodejs.  If you console.log id to see what's being passed to your async operations you will notice it's not what you would expect.

Comment: @PavelMarian are you going to use 8 in production? Without it a library is suggested.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what are you meaning by 8 ?